# NodeJS CI/CD pipeline 'apt-get' is not recognized issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a NodeJS application in GitLab. I have setup specific runner for the project in a windows environment. Below shows my pipeline that I have written.

```
image: node:14.16.0

stages:
  - Publish_QA

Publish_QA:
  tags:
    - ci
  stage: Publish_QA
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install zip --assume-yes
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo "$DEV_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
    - 'echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
  script:
    - echo "Deploying to DEV server"
    - zip -r build.zip *
    - ssh-add echo "$DEV_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
    - ssh -p22 ubuntu@$DEV_SERVER_IP "mkdir -p ~/nfs_api_tmp/ && rm -rf ~/nfs_api_tmp/*"
    - scp build.zip ubuntu@${DEV_SERVER_IP:~/nfs_api_tmp/}
    - ssh -p22 ubuntu@$DEV_SERVER_IP "rm -rf /var/www/html/nfs_api/* && unzip ~/nfs_api_tmp/build.zip -d /var/www/html/nfs_api/"
    - ssh -p22 ubuntu@$DEV_SERVER_IP "cd /var/www/html/nfs_api && yarn install"
    - ssh -p22 ubuntu@$DEV_SERVER_IP "cd /var/www/html/nfs_api && if pm2 list | grep nfs-dev; then pm2 restart nfs-dev; else pm2 start --name nfs-dev \"yarn server:qa\"; fi"
  only:
    - RELEASE_QA
  when: manual
```

I'm getting below error in Jobs. The error is because it is a Linux command
[image]

My devops knowledge is poor. How can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Not much to do except to either run it on Linux or find another "Windows way" of installing zip that does not involve the Linux only apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to change the image name to `image: node:14.16.0-alpine`**

To use with `apt-get` command you should install the node-alpine Linux version either you have to use `apk add` command.

Comment: when I add *apk add* runner gives me __The term 'apk' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program__ error

Answer (score 0):

**ensure you register a runner with docker executor**

it seems that your runner is shell executor

in runner machine use `gitlab-runner register` and use token in gitlab project settings CICD tab and `docker` executor.